# How to pass a float value into an event?

Tags: c#

I want to define a float value, "HalfDay" as 0 and then I want to add some values to that according user selections

```
public float HalfDay = 0.0f;

private void cmbStartDate_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (cmbStartDate.SelectedIndex == 0)
     {
         HalfDay = HalfDay + 0.5;
     }
 }

private void cmbEndDate_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (cmbEndDate.SelectedIndex == 0)
     {
         HalfDay = HalfDay - 0.5;
     }
}

lblNumberOfDays.Text = HalfDay.ToString();
```

But When I tried to do that, itoesn't show, previously defined "HalfDay" variable in auto suggest menu inside events. *(In here I've manually entered those values to give u an understanding about my target program.)*

Please somebody give me a correct programming code to accomplish that task.

Comment: Is this winforms or webforms?

Answer (score 2):

You could create an instance variable where it is accesible in the whole class.
Example:

```
public class MainForm : Form
{
    public float HalfDay = 0.0f;

    protected void cmbStartDate_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cmbStartDate.SelectedIndex == 0)
            HalfDay += 0.5f;

        lblNumberOfDays.Text = HalfDay.ToString();
    }

    protected void cmbEndDate_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cmbEndDate.SelectedIndex == 0)
            HalfDay -= 0.5f;

        lblNumberOfDays.Text = HalfDay.ToString();
    }
}
```

And check if the events are registered on the comboboxes.

Comment: This is not a `global` variable, but a field. Lets not get things confused.

Comment: You could even call it an instance variable.

Comment: Please give me the correct programming code if u could. I'm little bit new to C#. :)

Comment: @ThilinaSandunsiri Try something like this, you have to edit it yourself to have it fully working, this is just a hint.

Comment: @ThilinaSandunsiri No problem, this should help you, don't forget to set the text in your label in each event so it will always update the text

Comment: "HalfDay = HalfDay + 0.5;" line gives an error message. It says "cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'float'" What should I do?

Comment: Now. Its correct. I used it as "HalfDay = (float)(HalfDay - 0.5);"
Now it's ok.

Comment: @ThilinaSandunsiri Indeed, you can cast it like you did or use my version: `HalfDay += 0.5f`;